# How to substract n workdays from today to get a past date with user prompt?

Tags: r

I'm trying to count n workdays backwards from today to get an specific date.

I'd like to get a user input with the days to count backwards and let the system calculate that date.

Let's say I would like to count 100 (workdays) backwards from today.

```
A <- readline(prompt = "How many days backwards do you want to count? ")

#user input: 100

Date to be calculated <- Today date-A (format yyyy/mm/dd)

#Date to be calculated = 2018-03-02
```

Then I'll use the date to get some values of a dataset stored for that date.

Any comments will be highly appreciated

Comment: How about `Sys.Date() - 100`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Seems to work! Any way to substract 100 working days?

Comment: For that, you may need to check `bizdays`?

Comment: Will have a look. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't care about holidays and just want to know "what day was [x] weekdays  ago?" you can do `Sys.Date() - which(x == cumsum(!grepl("S.+", weekdays(Sys.Date() - 1:ceiling(x*1.5)))))[1]`

Comment: Great! Thanks Ryan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to write a recursive function to subtract weekdays. The `chron::is.weekend` function can be used to decide if a day is `working-day`.  Other option to decide `weekend/working-day` could be based on day starting with `S` as suggested by @Ryan.

```
library(chron)
substractWorkingDays <- function(x, n){
  v <- seq(x, x -n, by="-1 day")
  workingDays <- sum(!is.weekend(v[-1])) #One can check day name start with `S`
  if(workingDays == n){
    return(v[length(v)])
  }else{
    substractWorkingDays(v[length(v)], n-workingDays)
  }
}

#Testing it

substractWorkingDays(as.Date("2018-06-10"), 5)
#[1] "2018-06-04"
substractWorkingDays(as.Date("2018-06-10"), 10)
#[1] "2018-05-28"
substractWorkingDays(as.Date("2018-06-10"), 12)
#[1] "2018-05-24"
```