# Extract start date from date duration in R

Tags: r, date

Apologies if this seems convoluted.. I am trying to find the start date from exactly 252 business days from today (Sys.Date()).. its almost in a sense a reverse "NETWORKDAYS" function.

Inputs would include Networkdays = 252, today's date and holiday list. I tried using this networkdays function I found on stack overflow. The end goal is to extract the START DATE. Thank you very much!

```
networkdays <- function(start, end, holidays)
{
  dates <- seq(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), by="day")

  if(missing(holidays))holidays <- 0 else holidays <- length(holidays)
  sum(as.numeric(format(dates, "%w") > 1)) - holidays
}

networkdays()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substract n workdays from today to get a past date with user prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785263/how-to-substract-n-workdays-from-today-to-get-a-past-date-with-user-prompt)

Comment: The inputs would be the following

end date = today() / Sys.Date()
number of days = 252
holidays = c(12/25/19,.... etc)

output = 1/23/19

Comment: That code in the "How to substract n workdays" works but does not include certain holidays.. maybe we have a count function that looks at a list of holiday dates, counts them then adds it to 252?